# Visualization to show inside Tensorflow training in live

Tags: software-development, python, data-visualization, machine-learning

Kindly, suggest me is there any framework or application available that will help me look into the tensorflow training apart from Tensorboard.
The Tensorboard doesn't show me the lively training. It has all numbers what I am looking for is graphical. I have went through [Tensorflow Playground](https://playground.tensorflow.org). But it is not helping me in seeing the training. So I need something like that.
May be with Django or Flask or any other frame work that could help me have a deep look at my model training and testing.
Please suggest me people I am in dilemma.
I expect that everyone help me if there any code or repository please suggest.

**UPDATED DIAGRAM of EXPECTATION:**
See the following image:
[image: expected image]
I hope this helps.

Comment: "it is not helping me in seeing the training. So I need something like that." Is it a typo?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes something like that. But not the tensorboard as it was not making sense to me. But playground thus. But it is not using tensorflow at all.

Comment: Could you please draw a quick sketch (with paper or paint) showing what the graphical visualization could look like? In particular, please explain what values it should show. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I guess I have shared a link in the question. The exact diagram. I will update the question with the snapshot.

Comment: So you want something like this Playground visualization, but for your own training? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, I mean if I get some sample I could insert my model into it later. What you said is absolutely correct!